# mySQL Query to retrieve duration of values

Tags: mysql, duration

I have a mySQL table that stores events.  At a minimum, the table is written to once per hour and is also written whenever there is a change in value.  Entries are like this (each line is a row in the table)

1. DateTime                Value
2. 10/17/2013  01:00:00    0
3. 10/17/2013  01:45:00    1
4. 10/17/2013  02:00:00    1
5. 10/17/2013  03:00:00    1
6. 10/17/2013  03:30:00    0
7. 10/17/2013  04:00:00    0
8. 10/17/2013  04:15:00    1
9. 10/17/2013  05:00:00    1
10. 10/17/2013  05:23:00    0
11. 10/17/2013  06:00:00    0
12. 10/17/2013  07:00:00    0

Sorry the list above doesn't present well.  There is a DateTime Column and a Value column (1 or 0)
How can I write a query to tell me how long the value was a "1" Between 0300 and 0700 (as an example).  The value could change multiple times within an hour.  I do not need to query more often than on the hour.  In this example the result I'm looking for is 1.63 [hours]  (98 minutes).

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sur, But please try using some methods of database like DateAdd(),etc methods, please google it

Comment: The date portion is not a problem.  It is calculating the 'duration' that the value=1 is the problem for me.